# German piece of Identity for EU nationals

Tags: resident-permit, eu-citizens

I wonder whether Germany issues residence cards for EU citizens (even though unrequired) like France, Italy or Belgium.

So are these issued in Germany to EU nationals that want them or are the latter bound to use their national ID cards while dealing with everything there?